# How to Bring Value from State First load to second load in one page

Tags: reactjs, state-management

I want bring state from first load to second load, without reset state and without Redux,
if I Init state before load, then I setState for change to new Value, then I refresh or I re-call component(second load), without my state reset to init state(like first load), is imposible??

Comment: If you want to persist state across browser refresh, you will have to use local storage.

Comment: LocalStorage is used in such cases where you want to persist the state like in your scenario.

Comment: But I Minimalize Package and Resource Usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use local storage if you want to use it in the other tabs of the browser too.
Use session storage if you just want to store it in the same tab of the browser.

```
  state = {
    page_value: localStorage.getItem("page_value") || ''
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('onbeforeunload', this.compareValue())
  }

  compareValue(){
    const old_page_value = localStorage.getItem("page_value")
    if (this.state.page_value !== old_page_value){
       localStorage.setItem("page_value", this.state.page_value)
     }
  }
```